# Why sequelize changes my date hours to T00:00:00Z?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a simple model that has some date elements in it. This is the simplified model:

```
"user restrict"

var   moment   = require('moment');

module.exports = function(sequalize, DataTypes){
  var Reservation = sequalize.define('reservation', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    from: {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
    },
    expires: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    }

},{
hooks: {
    beforeCreate : function(reservation){
        var expiration = moment.utc().add('m', 10);
        reservation.expires = expiration;
        return reservation;
    }
  },
  timestamps: true,
  createdAt: 'createdAt',
  updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
  deletedAt: 'destroyTime',
  paranoid: true,
  freezeTableName: true 
});

   return Reservation;
}
```

The date parts for expires, createdAt and updatedAt are stored correctly but the time is changed to 00:00:00Z. Any thought why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think that's happening is that in the DB those fields are defined as DATE fields and not as DATETIME fields so the time is getting truncated.